# SQL yearly retention of Student

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working in Access. I have two tables [2015F] and [2016f] which both contains the current students of each year. I'm using the student_ID as the primary key for both.

This is how i'm currently getting the Freshmen retention rate that came back from 2015 to 2016

I created a new table from [2015F] that contained all the Freshmen. Then I created a new table from [2016F] that contained the student_id from 2015. Lastly I used the query below to get the students that were freshmen in 2015, that did not come back in 2016.

```
SELECT [2015Freshmen].*
FROM 2015Freshmen
WHERE [2015Freshmen.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID] NOT IN (SELECT  [2015Fenrolled16.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID]
FROM [2015Fenrolled16]
);
```

Is there an easier way to generate these results simply using [2015F] and [2016F] alone.

Im working in access database.

Comment: Why do you have SQL Server tagged, if you aren't using SQL Server?

Comment: @WEI_DBA oops. fixed. Thanks for the update

Comment: `Is there an easier way to generate these results simply using [2015F] and [2016F] alone.` Don't both tables contain the same data?

Comment: Why would you be creating separate tables for each year, rather than just having one table with the information about each student?

Answer (score 1):

Task: Return all records from 2015F that don't exist in 2016F.

One approach using a LEFT Join (return all 2015 records and the matching 2016 record if one exists. then exclude all records where a 216 record exists

```
SELECT * 
FROM 2015F 
LEFT JOIN 2016F
 on 2015F.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID = 2016F.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID
WHERE 2016F.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID is null
```

Or alternatively using a not exists and a correlated sub query
Return all 2015F records that don't exist in 2016F.  Assuming SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID is the same in both tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 2015F 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM 2016F
                  WHERE 2015F.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID = 2016F.SPRIDENSPRIDEN_ID)
```